# Is possible NEWSEQUENTIALID() repeat with NewId()?

Tags: sql-server, newid, newsequentialid

I used to have a table with about 1000W data, the primary key column's datatype is `uniqueidentifier`, and the default value is `Newid()`. Now there is a performance problem, and I want to change the default value to `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.

Is it possible for the GUID generated by `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` to duplicate the data previously saved (previously generated by `NewId()`)?

Comment: Keep in mind that `newsequentialid()` creates values "greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer since Windows was started".  When the OS is restarted, you'll get a new seed value, which may be lower than the previous one, causing index fragmentation.  See [this discussion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/53617).  Also, it specifically mentions windows--not sure how it behaves on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

`NEWSEQUENTIALID` effectively creates a [Version 1 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)).

`NEWID` creates a [Version 4 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)).

Although [`NEWSEQUENTIALID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does apply some [byte scrambling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/how-to-generate-sequential-guids-for-sql-server-in-net), it does leave the version nybble intact. This means that there's no chance of a collision between a `NEWSEQUENTIALID` created guid and a `NEWID` one.